# Polygons connecting to unknown point off QGIS map that was not designated?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I'm taking a methods course where we are currently learning how to take points in QGIS with an RTK GNSS system (Emlid Reach RS: https://emlid.com/reachrs/).

All of our points and lines show up OK, but when we attempt to make polygons, QGIS closes the polygon, but then attaches said polygon to some unknown point that we never desginated that goes *way* off of our map.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what may be causing this issue so we can fix it for next time?

[image: Polygons with Errors]

Comment: How is it grouping those points into polygons, as it looks like some errant point is being including in the grouping...